# Callback to calling function from socket.on message in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, socket.io, callback

I am using Socket.io together with Android.
I am having trouble to understand how I can pass back data to the calling function after I have received the data from the server.

I have one main method I use to send data to the server and receive them back it is the following method:

```
// Calling method
socketService.sendSocketMessage(CHECKFORNEWUSER, getApplicationContext(), Activity.this, true, user.getJSONObject());

 @Override
    public void sendSocketMessage(final String socketMessage, final Context context, final Activity activity, final boolean removeSocketListenerImmediately, final JSONObject jsonObject) {
        // Check if device has internet available
        if (isInternetAvailable(context, activity)) {
            // Send data to server
            socketService.emit(socketMessage, jsonObject);

            // Set message listener
            messageListener = new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    // Remove socket listener immediately
                    if (removeSocketListenerImmediately) {
                        removeSocketListener(socketMessage);
                    }

<<<< I want to callback to the calling method with data here, how do I do that?
                    socketCallback.callback(args); 
                }
            };

            // Call listener on receiving message
            socketService.on(socketMessage, messageListener);
        }
    }
```

Now what I don't understand is how I can best send the data back to the calling function? I cannot return the data as it is an asynchronous call within the call method. I was thinking of using a callback function, but I am really unclear as to how to do this best. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Ley `Activity` or `Fragmeny` implement `Emitter.Listener`.

Comment: Hi @MartinZeitler can you please elaborate this a bit more with an example how this would look like?